# Is pattern matching preferred or a case statement in idiomatic Erlang?

Tags: erlang, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Which one of this code is the preferred way in Erlang and why ?

```
sumOfMultiples(Multiples, 1) ->
  0;

sumOfMultiples(Multiples, N) ->
  cal_multiples(Multiples, lists:seq(1, N-1), 0).
```

or

```
sumOfMultiples(Multiples, N) ->
  case N of
    1 -> 0;
    cal_multiples(Multiples, lists:seq(1, N-1), 0)
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title isn't quite correct, because `case` *is* pattern matching (and an expression, not a statement).

There might be a slight preference for the multiple-clause definition because it's nicer to use when you want to match on more than one argument, but both are perfectly idiomatic.